# Python Flask Website on Azure (You do not have permission to view this directory or page.)

Tags: python, azure, flask

im trying to create a demo python flask website and publish it to microsoft azure. i take the python flask template from visual studio and publish it directly to azure from there with any changes.

[files on azure created by visual studio template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjYkq.png)

when i call the project i get the following error: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

[error: you do not have permission...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBDR5.png)

i am able to call the html files directly from the directory (display in html instead of python).

i dont know how to make the website run properly. I created the flask template in visual studio 2017 and published also from there without any code changes. what do i have to do to make it run? help is very appreciated :-)

Regards
Christian

Comment: solved the problem. i had to change the pricing plan and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just for summary:***

> Free Tier
>
> As with anything free, there is a trade-off – with this tier you get a
> maximum of 60 minutes CPU daily, with 1 GB RAM, 1 GB disk space and no
> SLA. You also can’t use a custom domain or SSL.

You can check the limits about the `azure app service pricing plans` via this [article](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2016/05/12/understanding-azure-app-service-plans-and-pricing/).

Comment: It's pleasure!  If you think my answer is useful, you could mark my answer for other members' reference on the forum.Thanks~