Accessing Azure Web App after deploying it
I have successfully deployed my (very simple) web app to Azure Web App after creating an App Service Plan. However, when I go to my-app-name.azurewebsites.net (where I replace my-app-name with the actual app name), I simply get this error: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
Does this indicate an error within my web app? Or does it literally mean that I still have to set some permissions regarding who can view the web app? (I have never deployed a web app to Azure before.)

can you Provide more details about your Application.

where I replace my-app-name with the actual app name What is this means.

what is the framework and version of your app?

where I replace my-app-name with the actual app name means that my-app-name is not the actual name of the app. And I'm using Flask.

@limitIntegral314 the error you are seeing, indicates there's an error with your deployment. Please check these and see if helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/how-to-debug-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1401699/correcting-the-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608417/python-flask-website-on-azure-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory

@Vinicius Deschamps, thank you for your comment.
I created a simple Python Flask app and deployed it to Azure Web App.
If you're using the free tier pricing plan, change to other plans.
For deploying a Python Flask app to Azure Web Apps, follow the steps below.
Below is my code.
app. py:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

requirements.txt:
Flask

I ran the following two commands to enable the virtual environment for deployment purposes.
python -m venv .venv 

.\.venv\Scripts\activate 

I deployed my Flask app to Azure using the VS Code Azure Extension, as shown below.

The deployment to Azure was successful, as shown below.

Check the Kudu by using the URL below:
https://<YourWebAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui.
Select File Manager and navigate to Site -> wwwroot, then check the output.tar.gz file as shown below.


Azure App service Output:


Thanks for your comment! Will this also work if I deploy my app using Docker? And what is the difference between a deployment via VS Code and directly doing this from within Azure?

Why do I get the feeling that these are all AI generated answers...

@limitIntegral314 Yes, you can deploy web app using Docker. Refer this so thread for deploying your app using docker through Azure Container registry.

@limitIntegral314 Deploying through Vs code helps to test your code locally before deploying to production you can check errors and bugs. It is developer friendly.
Deployment directly from Azure provides more Controller over the resources, It is visual approach. Mainly prefer for Large Deployments.
